# how to display PHP Multidimensional Arrays?

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array, display

how to display this using foreach in php?
I want to show it as a list.

```
$quantity=0;
        $quantities = array(
            array('Jan',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m1)),
            array('Feb',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m2)),
            array('Mar',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m3)),
            array('Apr',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m4)),
            array('May',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m5)),
            array('Jun',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m6)),
            array('Jul',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m7)),
            array('Aug',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m8)),
            array('Sep',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m9)),
            array('Oct',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m10)),
            array('Nov',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m11)),
            array('Dec',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m12)),
        );
        return $quantities;
```

Comment: Are you looking for something automatic like `print_r`? `var_dump`? If you want it formatted a certain way, use a for each like you said in your question. Iterate through it and echo out whatever HTML you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options, so based on your code (and what I added):

```
<?php
$quantity=0;

// Added this, so we have an object
$array = [
        "m1" => 1,
        "m2" => 2,
        "m3" => 3,
        "m4" => 4,
        "m5" => 5,
        "m6" => 6,
        "m7" => 7,
        "m8" => 8,
        "m9" => 9,
        "m10" => 10,
        "m11" => 11,
        "m12" => 12
    ];
// Converted array to object    
$ppmpitem = json_decode(json_encode($array));

$quantities = array(
    array('Jan',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m1)),
    array('Feb',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m2)),
    array('Mar',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m3)),
    array('Apr',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m4)),
    array('May',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m5)),
    array('Jun',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m6)),
    array('Jul',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m7)),
    array('Aug',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m8)),
    array('Sep',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m9)),
    array('Oct',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m10)),
    array('Nov',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m11)),
    array('Dec',($quantity += $ppmpitem->m12)),
);
// Pretty print
print("<pre>".print_r($quantities,true)."</pre>");
// As a list where Month is key
foreach($quantities as $key => $value) {
    $month = [
            $quantities[$key][0] => $quantities[$key][1]
        ];
    $months[$quantities[$key][0]]  = $quantities[$key][1];
    print_r($month);   
}

//Also print full array of months:
print_r($months);
```

Results are:
Pretty print:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jan
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Feb
            [1] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mar
            [1] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Apr
            [1] => 10
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => May
            [1] => 15
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jun
            [1] => 21
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jul
            [1] => 28
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Aug
            [1] => 36
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sep
            [1] => 45
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => Oct
            [1] => 55
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Nov
            [1] => 66
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => Dec
            [1] => 78
        )

)
</pre>
```

Print out "list":

```
Array
(
    [Feb] => 3
)
Array
(
    [Mar] => 6
)
Array
(
    [Apr] => 10
)
Array
(
    [May] => 15
)
Array
(
    [Jun] => 21
)
Array
(
    [Jul] => 28
)
Array
(
    [Aug] => 36
)
Array
(
    [Sep] => 45
)
Array
(
    [Oct] => 55
)
Array
(
    [Nov] => 66
)
Array
(
    [Dec] => 78
)
```

Or print one array (month as key)

```
Array
(
    [Jan] => 1
    [Feb] => 3
    [Mar] => 6
    [Apr] => 10
    [May] => 15
    [Jun] => 21
    [Jul] => 28
    [Aug] => 36
    [Sep] => 45
    [Oct] => 55
    [Nov] => 66
    [Dec] => 78
)
```

BR

Answer (score 1):

You may create an array filled from 1 to 12 and apply the `array_reduce` to get your output.

```php
<?php

class P {
    public $m1 = 1;
    public $m2 = 1;
    public $m3 = 1;
    public $m4 = 1;
    public $m5 = 1;
    public $m6 = 1;
    public $m7 = 1;
    public $m8 = 1;
    public $m9 = 1;
    public $m10 = 1;
    public $m11 = 1;
    public $m12 = 1;

    public function __construct() {
    }
}

$ppmpitem = new P();

$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

$quantities = array_reduce($array, function ($carry, $item) use ($ppmpitem) {
    $month = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $item)->format('M');
    $carry['total'] +=  $ppmpitem->{"m" . $item};
    $carry['quantities'][] = [$month, $carry['total']];
    return $carry;
}, ['total' => 0, 'quantities' => []])['quantities'];

var_dump($quantities);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of ways to display a multidimensional array including use of the default PHP's `print_r()` function. Besides if you want a more precise way of accessing the elements and displaying them you can use a looping criteria such as `for()` or `foreach()`. Sample :

```
foreach($quantities as $qty){
    print_r($qty);
}
```

Comment: How is this printing out array? This prints string..

Comment: had initially demonstrated on how to print the array values .. `print_r()` can be used to print the arrays.